# How to create clustered index on multiple columns using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 non clustered index, one on column A and one on column B. I want to edit the .hbm.xml file to remove these index and create one clustered index on the combination of Column A and B. What would be the attribute to use in the hbm.xml file?
I donot want to use annotations in the persisting java file, since the existing code will have to be modified. Please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple columns can be grouped into the same index by simply specifying the same index name.

```
<property name="columnA" index="CustName"/>
<property name="columnB" index="CustName"/>
```

Comment: Hi
Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try the same. Would that be a clustered index or a non-clustered index? I am using MSSQL.

Comment: By default clustered index is enabled in the ID column of each of my tables. I have an <id> tag which has auto-increment enabled using  <generator class="native"/>. Is it possible to create a clustered index on the properties A and B as you mentioned/

Comment: There may only be ONE clustered IDX per table. By using this as a default makes it difficult for the app developer or DBA to quickly add or change the once-per-table opportunity to use the cluster to improve query performance. More about this topic: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3305